# Multiple Ajax Request waits each other to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to send multiple ajax requests. But each request waits for previous one complete to start.
Is there any reason for that?

Here is my JS code.

```
tjq.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: _id },        
    dataType: 'json',        
    url: '/dynamic-packages?act=addtocart',        
    success: function (r) {
        ///...
    }
});
```

Here is the C# code. I just put a sleep for 10 sec to demonstrate duration in developer console.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Request["act"] == "addtocart")
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Response.End();
    }        
}
```

As you can see the SS duration increases by 10 sec for each request.

[image: Developer console]

**UPDATE**:

Here is how I call ajax request

```
for (var i = 0; i < Destinations.length; i++) {
    getHotels(i);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of multiple ajax requests that you are using?

Comment: I used for loop to call ajax. But it did not make any difference when I call it repeatedly.

Comment: Is c# (or at least the controller handling the calls) single-threaded? 

Then this would make sense. Your loop performs three ajax requests almost at the same time (the loop is not waiting for one request to succeed). All three requests hit the server which sleeps 10s before performing the 2nd request, but then sleeps again 10s before performing the third request – leading to a 30s delay at the end. :)

Comment: it is asp.net web form application. I sent request to codebehind aspx.cs of the same page. I am not sure it is single-threaded. How can I make it multi-thread?

Answer (score 0):

Use *async* statement for give prority in first or next it. 
Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called. If you set async: true then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet.

**async: false**

```
function getData1(){

  var data;

    var param1 = jQuery('field1').val();
    var param2 = jQuery('field2').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "ajx_request1.php", 
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
       'field1': param1, 
       'field2': param2
    },
        dataType: "json",
    async: false, 
    success: function(result){
        data=result;
      },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
    });

  return data;

}

function getData2() {
  var data;
    var param1 = jQuery('field1').val();
    var param2 = jQuery('field2').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "ajx_request2.php", 
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
       'field1': param1, 
       'field2': param2
    },
        dataType: "json",
    async: false, 
    success: function(result){
        data=result;
      },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
    });

  return data;


  return data;
}

getData1();
getData2();
```

**You Can Also Set Timeout for response get late another from one statement.**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var data = getData2();
    console.log("The data is: " + data);
},1000);
```